# The distance moved by the tip of the hand in clock.

Tags: geometry

> The minute hand of a clock is $15$ cm
>   long. The distance moved by the tip
>   of the hand in $35$ minutes is

$a.)\ 35\pi \\
\color{green}{b.)\ \dfrac{35\pi}{2}} \\
c.)\ \dfrac{5\pi}{4} \\
d.)\ \dfrac{5\pi}{2} $

For minute hand,

$12\ hrs =360^{\circ} \\
35\ min=\left(\dfrac{35}{2}\right)^{\circ} $

Distance$=\dfrac{2\pi 15\times 35}{360\times 2}=\dfrac{35\pi}{24}\ cm $

But that is not in options

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12th$ grade.

Comment: The minute hand takes only one hour, not twelve, to make a complete circuit around the face of the clock. So in 35 minutes it moves 12 times as far as your calculations showed. Except for that mistake, your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has moved $\frac{35}{60}$ of a full circle (a full circle consists of $60$ minutes, and it has moved $35$ of those). A full circle is $2\pi\cdot15cm=30\pi cm$. It has therefore moved a total of
$$
\frac{35}{60}\cdot30\pi cm=\frac{35\pi}{2}cm
$$

Comment: what is mistake in my answer ?

Comment: @RK Your mistake is that 35 minutes doesn't translate to $\left( \frac{35}{2} \right)^\circ$. That's only $17.5^\circ$, while 35 minutes is more than half-way around the clock: Definitely at least $180^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

First you can set up a proportion to find the central angle it has moved,

35/60=x/360→x=210

Then you can use the arc length formula
arc length  = 2πr(x/360) = 2π(15)(210/360)=35π/2.

Answer (score 0):

The question is referring to the MINUTE hand, NOT hour hand. Read it properly.
The MINUTE hand does not only move 360 degrees in 12 hours. That's the HOUR hand. The MINUTE hand moves 360 degrees in an hour. This is because the MINUTE cycle restarts after an hour. It moves the full clock around after ONE hour, NOT TWELVE hours. So, there lies your mistake.